# How to quickly checkout between git worktrees?

Tags: git, terminal, git-worktree

I have the following file structure

```
❯ tree -L 1
.
├── latex/
├── main/
├── simulator/
├── tscnn/
```

Each directory is a worktree. If I am on `latex/`, trying to to check out to another worktree yields

```bash
❯ git checkout main
fatal: 'main' is already checked out at '/path/to/main'
```

I want to quickly checkout to another worktree (that is, `cd` to another directory) without explicitly writing the path (e.g., in the previous example, `/path/to/main`)

How to do so?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid using `cd`? anyway.... Use `git checkout --detach`, then it won't matter that a branch is already checked out in a different worktree (because, you _won't_ checkout it out twice because you are detaching).

Comment: Having checked out branches in other worktrees blocks you from checking out a branch in the current worktree conveniently—you're working against yourself. Detach all the branches in the other worktrees. Then you can checkout branches conveniently.

Comment: @eftshift0 *Why do you want to avoid using cd?* Unproductive workflow. In a nested directory of a worktree, it is cumbersome to `cd` to another worktree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do that with Git but possible with a shell function that'd use additional Unix tools. This works for me:

```bash
cd_worktree() {
    if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then
        echo "Usage: cd_worktree <branch>" >&2
        return 1
    fi
    path="$(git worktree list | grep -F "$1" | awk '{print $1}')"
    if [ -n "$path" ]; then
        cd "$path"
    else
        echo "Cannot find path for branch '$1'" >&2
        return 1
    fi
}
```

Usage:

```bash
cd_worktree main
```

For bash completion add this to your `~/.bashrc`:

```bash
    _cd_worktree_comp() {
        local cur="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"
        COMPREPLY=(`compgen -W "$(
            git worktree list | awk '{s=$3; gsub("[\\\\[\\\\]]", "", s); print s}'
        )" -- "$cur"`)
    }

    _cd_worktree_comp_loader() {
        _completion_loader git
        unset _cd_worktree_comp_loader
        complete -F _cd_worktree_comp cd_worktree
        return 124
    }

    complete -F _cd_worktree_comp_loader cd_worktree
```

It relies on `_completion_loader` from package `bash-completion`.

Comment: Added bash completion.