# Git alias to cd to worktree directory or otherwise checkout branch

Tags: git

I need git checkout to work even if I have checked out a branch in a worktree. For my needs, changing to that directory instead would be ideal. Doesn't need to change directory on my shell command line, so git alias should work in principle.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77266926/7976758

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that `git checkout` has a `--ignore-other-worktrees` option that does precisely this. This doesn't change directory to the worktree directory, but it works just as well for me.

Context: I have the `git cp-donate` alias in my `.gitconfig`, and I need it to work even in repos where I'm using worktrees:

```
[alias]
        cp-donate = "!f() { \
            set -eu; \
            if [ $# -lt 1 ]; then \
                echo Usage: git cp-donate BRANCH \\[CHERRY-PICK-ARGS\\] 1>&2; \
                return 1; \
            fi; \
            branch=$1; shift; \
            git checkout --ignore-other-worktrees \"$branch\"; git pull; \
            if [ $# -ge 2 ]; then git cherry-pick \"$@\"; fi; \
            git push; git checkout --ignore-other-worktrees -; git rebase --autosquash \"$branch\"; \
        }; f"
```

Comment: The question is unclear, this doesn't even actually answer it, and the "solution" is given without much explanations. I didn't downvote but... the whole thing needs work.

Comment: @RomainValeri I agree it needs work, but I addressed my need. Feel free to edit or reply if you have a better answer.